# Does Struts 1 create a controller object for each session or is the controller classes singletons?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, struts

I have a Struts 1/Spring 2 application. I am wondering is my `Action` classes are **Singletons** shared by all *session* or if each *user/session* gets a new object of the `Action` class?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that Struts Action class is implemented as a singleton,but I can say that the framework just uses one instance of it and only one instance is used to process all incoming requests, care must be taken not to do something with in the Action class that is not thread safe. From the [javadoc](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts/action/Action.html):

Actions must be programmed in a thread-safe manner, because the controller will share the same instance for multiple simultaneous requests. This means you should design with the following items in mind:

1. *Instance and static variables MUST NOT be used to store information related to the state of a particular request. They MAY be used to share global resources across requests for the same action.*
2. *Access to other resources (JavaBeans, session variables, etc.) MUST be synchronized if those resources require protection. (Generally, however, resource classes should be designed to provide their own protection where necessary.*

---

**EDIT :**

This is what the official [Apache Struts](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/comparing-struts-1-and-2.html) page says :

***Struts 1 Actions are singletons** and must be thread-safe since there will only be one instance of a class to handle all requests for that Action. The singleton strategy places restrictions on what can be done with Struts 1 Actions and requires extra care to develop. Action resources must be thread-safe or synchronized.*